# The Unique ID still shows up as Winning GPO in Group Policy Results even after it is deleted

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, group-policy

I have deleted a group policy object in Group Policy Management Window. I thought this would also delete all the links to policies, but the links are still there in Group Policy Results and it is showing the unique ID of the policy instead of the policy name like the picture below. I have also checked C:\Windows\SYSVOL\sysvol{my domain}\Policies folder and made sure there is no folder in there whose name is the same as the policy name. Now I have no idea why it is still showing the unique ID. Is there any way to completely delete the policy? I know this is a trivial question, but I have been wasting a lot of time to just try to delete the links. Any advice would be appreciated.

[Group Policy Results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REYgB.png)

[Spec]
Machine: Windows Server 2008 R2 64bit

Comment: Seeing as these are User Configuration settings, have you logged out and back in?

Comment: I just did it, but still the same... I am new to the Group Policy, so I appreciate any advice. Thank you.